# Animated footers in HTML

Tags: css, animation

So, I've got a footer with three icons in. I've set it to be stuck at the bottom of the webpage, and I'd like it to fade in with an animation. I'm using the same "appear-animation" as for my other sections in the body, however this one is misbehaving!

The footer does take 800ms to appear, but there's no animation - it just appears there all of a sudden! I also tried FadeInDown, and got the same result.

Code is part of Porto HTML5 template.

HTML:

```
    <div class="appear-animation" data-appear-animation=fadeInUp" data-appear-animation-delay="800">
        <footer id="footer" class="color color-secondary short">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 center">
                        <ul class="social-icons mb-md">
                            <li class="social-icons-fa-github"><a href="https://github.com" target="_blank" title="GitHub"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-icons-linkedin"><a href="www.linkedin.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-icons-stack-overflow"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateY(20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
}
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform: translateY(20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
}
```

}

```
 @keyframes fadeInUp {
0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
}

100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    }
     }

 .fadeInUp {
 -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
 -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
 -o-animation-name: fadeInUp;
animation-name: fadeInUp;
```

Comment: Where's the CSS/JS?

Comment: Updated. Apologies.

Comment: I assume some JS is adding the `.fadeInUp` class, and the JS is probably being broken by a missing quote mark on your first line of HTML: `data-appear-animation=fadeInUp"` (Missing the opening `"`)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I added that missing " mark, and now the animation works as intended. However, my footer has floated away from the bottom where it's meant to be fixed! FadeInDown also has this problem.

However, the "FadeIn" animation places it at the bottom. This animation looks great, so I'll roll with it.